# Libreoffice Calc reference cell with a specific progression

Tags: libreoffice

I have a collumn with this contend inside:

```
=sheet1.F8   
=sheet1.F15   
=sheet1.F22
```

Normally in the excel I select the three cells and pull down, excel understand the logic and the next cell above will be "sheet1.F29". But if I do this in Libreoffice it puts "sheet1.F11".

Do you have any idea of how to do this ? (I have several sheets like this logic and I'd like to use Libreoffice instead Excel).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround and replying here:

It is setting the reference to “F11” because the first row contains a reference to F8 and the new entry is 3 rows beneath this i.e., the offset is based on the first cell of the selection, thus 8+3=11. A workaround is to use the addresses of the destination and combine this with the INDIRECT() function. For example, create a separate column with “Sheet1.F8”, “Sheet1.F15”, and Sheet1.F22” etc. Highlight and drag this column of values to obtain a column of correct address references. Then adjacent to this use (given “Sheet1.F8” in sheet 2 cell A1) =INDIRECT(A1) in B1. Now drag this down the B column to obtain the required values.